# Wrap a table with two columns of data (only after a specific row of that data) into another column

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to wrap a table that has two columns of data only after a specific row of that data, such as either from the middle or from a certain `<tr>`, such as the one shown below that contains `<td>Here:</td>`.

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A:</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A:</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A:</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A:</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A:</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Here:</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A:</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A:</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A:</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A:</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A:</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A:</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A:</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Is it possible in pure CSS or maybe JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could reset display to grid and select the previous row of "Here" to dispatch the rest in a second column.

possible example;

```css
table {
  width: max-content;
}

table,
tbody,
tr {
  display: grid;
}

tbody,
tr {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
}

tr {
  grid-column: 1;
}

tbody>tr:nth-child(5)~tr {
  grid-column: 2;
}

table,
td,
tbody:after {
  border: solid 1px;
  margin: 1px;
}

tbody:after {
  padding:0.15em;
  content: '?? a void to fill';
  grid-row: auto /span 10;
  background: #bad;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A:</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A:</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A:</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A:</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A:</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Here:</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A:</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A:</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A:</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A:</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A:</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A:</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A:</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much this was what I needed

Comment: Incredible, this is just what i was looking for too!

Answer (score -1):

If you mean like to splitter for new column, I guess this code for split column
With `<th>.......</th>`

**Your code is:**

```
<tr>
   <td>Here:</td>
   <td>B</td>
</tr>
```

**I'm changed with**

```
     <tr>
      <th scope="col" colspan="2">SPLITTER</th>
    </tr>
```

So will get output like in this Snippet:

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A:</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>A:</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>A:</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>A:</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>A:</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" colspan="2">SPLITTER</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A:</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>A:</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>A:</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>A:</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>A:</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>A:</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>A:</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```