# HTML table: Wrap multiple rows to new line

Tags: html, css, epub

I am using HTML and CSS to display sentences aligned with word-by-word IPA transcriptions:

```
<table>
  <tr class="eng">
    <td>This </td>
    <td>is</td>
    <td>an</td>
    <td>example</td>
    <td>sentence.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="ipa">
    <td>ðɪs</td>
    <td>ɪz</td>
    <td>ən</td>
    <td>ɪɡˈzæmpl̩</td>
    <td>ˈsɛntəns</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```
tr.eng {
  font-weight: bold;
}

tr.ipa {
  font-style: italic;
}

td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
}

.eng td:first-child {
  text-align: left;
}

.eng td:last-child {
  text-align: right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2ab9pgmd/

If a sentence is too long for the screen, I would like both rows to wrap to a new line, so that it could look like following hard-coded example:

```
<table>
  <tr class="eng">
    <td>This </td>
    <td>is</td>
    <td>an</td>
    <td>example</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="ipa">
    <td>ðɪs</td>
    <td>ɪz</td>
    <td>ən</td>
    <td>ɪɡˈzæmpl̩</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr class="eng">
    <td>sentence.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="ipa">
    <td>ˈsɛntəns</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Is it possible to set up an HTML table to wrap multiple rows to new lines dynamically depending on the screen size, rather than manually defining the line lengths in advance?

I found a similar example of what I would like to do [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17159819/9489502), but this solution does not keep the columns aligned for tables with more than one row.

If possible, I would rather not use JavaScript so the text can be viewed as an eBook.

Comment: Try using CSS grid instead of a table. Table rows aren't designed to wrap

Comment: This question is similar to this other question that asks how to wrap two table columns into a new column, but this question involves wrapping two rows instead of two columns https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64931699/wrap-a-table-with-two-columns-of-data-only-after-a-specific-row-of-that-data-i

Answer (score -1):

I prefer you go with the CSS Grid cause when you use table row for wrapping it wont get wrapped up and wont provide you the desired output . You can add wrapping rules but I don't think it will work.